# Android: Static Arraylist is becoming empty in service

Tags: android, android-service, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have declared a **static Arraylist** variable inside a service file (backgroundService.java). I am updating the static variable once i received a Push Message (using GCM). I am using 4.0.4 Device(Samsung S3).. The static variable becomes empty, once my app goes background and then if i long press the memu button and Swipes my application(Once we swipe the app is getting finished but not force stopped),the service is paused for a while and again started i.e, the service onDestroy method is not called instead OnCreate method is after that pause.. **After that pause the static ArrayList becomes empty. How to resolve it ? I dont want my static Arraylist to lose its value..**

This problem occurs in Android Version 4.0+ devices only.

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service
```

{
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

```
Context mContext;

String LOG_TAG=BackgroundService.class.getSimpleName();
    ApplicationInfo ai;
    private static boolean isRunning = false; 
public static ArrayList<String> mDMPush=new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
      super.onCreate();
      Log.e(LOG_TAG,"on create ");
      isRunning = true; 


}


@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    super.onStart(intent, startId);  


    Log.e(LOG_TAG,"mDMPush"+mDMPush);

    Log.e(LOG_TAG,"mDMPush outside if else "+mDMPush.size()+"   "+mDMPush.isEmpty());
            startService();



}

public static boolean isRunning() 
{ 
    return isRunning; 
} 

private void startService()
{        
   int delay = 100;
   int period =500;
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

   timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
       public void run() 
       {

        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
        try {
                 ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
                 if ((ai.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {


                       **Iam doing an action inside this timer using that arraylist mDMPush.. I ll add value to the arraylist once i received a push***              

                 }
           } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
           }



       }
     }, delay, period);

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a static?

Comment: Post your activity code with static arraylist declaration and use.

Comment: Because based on the static arraylist value i am doing an action in background.

Comment: post your code to get better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how you have to save array list in persistence storage

```
  Set<String> localStore = new HashSet<String>();
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    localStore.addAll(list);
    SharedPreferences ssidPref = getSharedPreferences("ssidPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor EDITIOR = ssidPref.edit();
                EDITIOR.putStringSet("ssidStored", localStore);
                EDITIOR.commit();
```

to Read

```
localStore = ssidPref.getStringSet("ssidStored", null);
```

Comment: I have a doubt in this code.. I will dynamically change my arraylist,i.e once i receive a push i ll change my arraylist according to it..How to use this at that scenario

Comment: this code tell you how to save array list in persistence storage so you have to check if push received and value change from the last update the old

Comment: Then how i could take the value from this SharedPreferences ?.. if i need to process

Comment: SharedPreferences.Editor EDITIOR = ssidPref.edit();
                EDITIOR.putStringSet("ssidStored", localStore);
                EDITIOR.commit();
call this where ever you need to change

Comment: updated my code to read as well so if this resolve your problem can you vote up my answer

Comment: S almost but how to put that local store to my array list i.e after localStore = ssidPref.getStringSet("ssidStored", null);

Comment: I need to put like this to transfer it to the arraylist  list.addAll(localStore);?

Comment: List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); localStore = ssidPref.getStringSet("ssidStored", null);
   list.addAll(localStore);

Comment: one min i ll  check and if it resolve my pbm i ll click Check ur answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you application process is getting killed and re-created, which is a normal thing on Android. You should not rely on a static state, save it to more persistent storage like preferences or db.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this page to find a better method to implement the storage of the array list [Android Persistent Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)